# Can we apply for dependent visa based on German Job seeker visa?

Tags: visa, germany, dependent-visa

I want to apply for German job seeker visa. Is it possible to apply Dependent visa for my family? If yes then can I apply these both simultaneously or it requires a gap? Can anyone throw some light on it?

Answer (score 1):

According to [section 29 clause 1 of the German residence act](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p0369) (which regulates dependent visa)

> For the purposes of subsequent immigration to join a foreigner,
>
> 1. the foreigner must possess a settlement permit, an EU long-term residence permit, a residence permit or an EU Blue Card, and
> 2. sufficient living space must be available.

As a job seeker visa does not fulfill the criteria it is not possible to get a dependent visa.

If you would apply to any of the visa in Nr. 1 you could do so simultaneously, it is even advisable if both live currently abroad (29.1.2.2 VwV-AufenthG).